# Scope with joins to get data in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Coming from Rails 2 to Rails 3 I've never worked so hard to understand something (side editorial).

Anyway, In a Rails 3 app i have the following models...

User:

```
has_many :answers
```

Answer:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :question
scope :user_answers, where (:user_id => current_user.id)
```

Question:

```
has_many :answers
scope :qs_w_user_ans, joins(:questions) & (:user_answers)
```

The current error i am getting is "undefined method `includes_values' for :user_answers:Symbol"

There is a Question id and a User id. Each answer has question_id and user_id.

I need the questions with a user's answers linked appropriately via the ids. Can you show me where my models are wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `&` operator (which I believe is recently deprecated) is an alias for `merge`, which allows you to essentially merge scopes. `:user_answers` isn't a scope, so you can't use this method.

As Dinatih pointed out, you can call joins multiple times. In this case, creating different scopes for each join won't buy you much, so his method suits your case.

More info on scopes: http://archives.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html

**Update**

Sorry for my misunderstanding. `:user_answers` is a scope, but you're not calling it correctly in this case. You want the following:

```
scope :qs_w_user_ans, joins(:questions) & Answer.user_answers
```

When merging scopes, you call the merged scopes like class methods.

In the article I linked, the scope `:published` on `Post` is merged with the scope `:published` on `User`:

```
scope :published, lambda {
  joins(:posts).group("users.id") & Post.published
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @McStretch. I read that article... but i'll reread it to see if it will help.

Comment: Thanks, @McStretch. Why is "user_answers" not a scope? I thought using "scope" made it a scope. Did you see it in the Answer model?

Comment: @Jay - no I'm sorry I missed that. I'll update my answer to reflect my new understanding.

Comment: Thanks, @McStretch. With this help... getting close enough to sniff out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4

```
Question.joins(Answer.user_answers)
```

[ http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables ]

Comment: `Question.joins(:answers).merge(Answer.user_answers)`

Answer (score -1):

```
joins(:questions).joins(:user_answers)
```