# Scoping with Model association in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

There are two models: **Discount** and **TimeDiscount**.

Discount `has_one` TimeDiscount and TimeDiscount `belongs_to` Discount.

I need to get all `TimeDiscounts` with associated `Discount.is_enabled` equals `true`. How can I do it? I know about scoping, and I can do something similar to this thing:

```
scope :new_orders, -> { where(order_status: OrderStatus.new_order) }
```

Please tell me how to make use of associations here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874118/scope-with-joins-to-get-data-in-rails-3

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
Discount.where(is_enabled: true).map do |discount|
  discount.time_discounts
end
```

This will return an array of TimeDiscount that match your requirement

Comment: For better performance and to be a bit more concise you can use `Discount.includes(:time_discount).where(is_enabled: true).map(&:time_discounts).flatten`

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
TimeDiscount.includes(:discount).where(discount: {is_enabled: true})
```

I believe this may also work:

```
TimeDiscount.includes(:discount).merge(Discount.is_enabled)
```

(but I would have to double check that one)

Answer (score 0):

In **Discount** Model,

```
scope :Active_Orders, -> { where(is_enabled: true) }
```

Then, fetch TimeDiscount for enabled discounts,

```
@Active_TimeDiscounts = Discount.Active_Orders.map{|active_ord| active_ord.TimeDiscount}
```

Hope it helps :)